# Connect two grounding rods

Tags: grounding

I added an exterior TV antenna and a grounding rod next to it with a 6 gauge copper wire going to both the antenna mast and the ground on the coax coming from the antenna.   It is about 15 feet from our electrical panel and after reading a bit more I have found that I need to bond the two rods together with a 6 gauge wire.  The grounding rod for the house is inside a garage wall with a stucco exterior.

Can the wire for connecting the two grounding rods enter the attic under the eves and cross a portion of the attic and go down an interior wall?

What I would like to do is clamp the new wire to the wire that goes from the coax to the new ground rod and run it into the attic and down the inside of the garage wall, cut an access point into the wall where the house ground wire comes up to the breaker box and clamp it to that wire.  Is that an acceptable way to do it?

Comment: Where is your breaker box located, inside or outside?

Comment: It is located outside.

Comment: Does the grounding electrode conductor from the breaker box exit the box then run into the wall, or does it run straight inside out of the back of the breaker box?  (It's pretty distinctive as it's often bare, and it'll be the only bare wire exiting the box if so.)

Comment: The box is inset into the exterior of the wall and they just drilled a small hole in the bottom of the breaker box and the large copper wire from, what I'm assuming is, the grounding rod disappears through it and into the wall.  There isn't any sort of access panel on the inside wall or below there on the outside.

Comment: How hard would it be to simply run the grounding wire from the antenna ground rod back to the breaker panel itself?

Comment: Pretty much the same as what I was planning.  From what I've read for lightening strikes I'm supposed to avoid sharp corners with the grounding wire and not run it parallel to other wires.  That makes it a bit more challenging since it sounds like I can't push it down the conduit that the house wiring leaves the breaker box through.  Going along the ground on the outside and then up the wall would make it difficult to avoid a sharp corner at the end.  If it is allowed I could go through the attic, down the inside of the garage wall (behind a shelf) and into the back of the breaker panel.

Comment: Is the "sharp corner at the end" a matter of the grounding wire trying to go from horizontal to vertical, or around some corner of the house?

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you are doing is fine.  IV Grounding Methods ,  In the code 820.100  coaxial cable shall be grounded. 820-100  (A) through (D).   (A) (1) Grounding Conductor , shall  be insulated and shall be listed.  (2) Material copper solid or stranded.   (3) Size , shall not be smaller than #14 awg and shall not be required to be larger than #6 awg.   (4) Length ,run as short as practicable,not to exceed 20 feet in length.   EXCEPTION,  If you can not have that length,a ground rod may be used in dwellings.  Run the cable as straight as you can.  And protect the wire from physical damage,where you go into stucco sleeve wire in sch80 pvc conduit. And you may want to run conduit on inside wall of garage to electrode, or if that is the main panel to the ground lugs. all connected and bonded .